# Identifying unique browsers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a multiplayer site in Rails, and I need a reliable way of blocking computers from using the site. For example, someone has been banned from the site multiple times, and there should be a way to block their computer from using the site.

I would find a way to do this with IP addresses but they're not always static are they? Also I'm asking about identifying browsers so that if there was unauthorised access from a different browser or machine, then I could implement a security feature to make sure the account belonged to them. I would also need to store these locations as trusted locations in a database, hashed.

Comment: There is almost no use in identifying browsers since changing user agent is way too easy, with a plugin for example. Banning user account or IP is enough in most cases.

Comment: To "trust" a machine/browser pair, you could try cookies. There are various methods of making them more secure.